# Como imprimir html en AngularJS (Angular 1)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Vale amigos, estoy usando angular y jquery.

Estoy corriendo un `ng-repeat`.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" ng-repeat="hab in habilities">
    <div class="card custom">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{hab.name}}</h4>
            {{hab.calification | toHabilitiesStar}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`toHabilitiesStar` es una directiva que he creado que me retorna un string en html; hasta aquí todo bien.

He investigado y me tope con y con [angualar sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml), lo he integrado de la siguiente manera

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
```

Pero la consola me arroja este error `[$injector:modulerr]`

- ya me descarue el archivo y lo integré en mi head despues de angular.js y ya borré caché.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifica que la version de `ngSanitize` sea la correcta. Usa la siguiente `URL`:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-sanitize.js
```

Donde `X.Y.Z` corresponde a la versión de `Angular.js` que estés utilizando. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo que usa `ngSanitize`:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngSanitize"]);

app.controller("customHTML", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.html = "<div>Esto es un <strong>HTML</strong> devuelto desde un controlador</div>";

}]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="customHTML" ng-bind-html="html"></div>
</div>
```

Aunque lo más sencillo es que utilices el servicio `$sce` y así evitas cargar `ngSanitize`. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("customHTML", ["$scope", "$sce", function ($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml("<div>Esto es un <strong>HTML</strong> devuelto desde un controlador</div>");

}]);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="customHTML" ng-bind-html="html"></div>
</div>
```